# Side by Side Bar Charts for similar quantities in Tableau

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, tableau-api, infovis, stacked-chart

I am new to Tableau but have rather simple visualization in need.

Suppose I have a table with 3 columns of, 
{Val_A, Err_Model_AB (in %), Err_Model_AC (in %)},
and 100 rows.

The parameter Val_A takes random values from [0,1] and the 'Err_Model's go from [-10:10].

Now I want a a side-by-side bar graph with:

**x-axis:** 'Bins' of Val_A with interval 0.1 (so 0-0.1, 0.1-0.2 .. 0.9-1)

**y-axis:** 'Count' of Values of Err_Model

**side-by-side color:** Red=Err_Model_AB , Green = Err_Model_AC

But Tableau does not understand this!

It lets me make a scatter plot of (Val_A vs. Err_Val_AB) & another one with Err_Val_B.

But what I want is count of all values of Err_Val_AB within the range of Val_A from 0-0.1, 0.1-0.2 .. 0.9-1. And similar side-by-side bar for Err_Val_AC

Any thoughts ?  I don't mind shifting it to MATLAB or any other relatively easy infovis software.

Comment: Don't have my Tableau to test now, but try selecting the measures and dimensions, go to Show Me and select side-by-side bars

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the BINS? Not hard, right click the dimenstion, Create Bins, and you Bin size should be 0.1

Drag this Bin dimension to Column.

Now drag both Err_Model_AB and Err_Model_AC to Columns. If they're not already Count, right click them, measure, count.

Now go to show me, and select side-by-side bars.

And voilà, I think that's what you want